# How to model a customized set out of a defined set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have a model `question` which contains a defined set of survey questions.
These questions are defined by us, but the customer is free to either use the defined set or customize the set to his own liking by modifying, removing or adding questions to the defined set. The issue I have is how to model this.

Option 1: create a many_to_many relation between `customer` and `question` to store the customized question when needed. This works for modifying existing questions, but how about new questions or removed questions?

Option 2: create a one-to-many relation between  `customer` and `customerquestion` and copy the whole set of defined questions into `customerquestion` when a new customer is created. This will create a lot of duplicate records when the customer hardly makes changes. Also what about synchronisation between the default set and the customer set when there is a change in the default set?

What would be the best option, how should I model this? And am I missing a better solution for this situation?

Comment: my suggestion would be use option 1 and for adding new questions maintain a column in question table to mark default. By default it will have value 0 which means default question. Instead store customer_id who added that question and many_to_many will link customer with that question. Hope I am clear.

Comment: If I read 'set of questions' I guess you should consider also including a Questionnaire model... and I agree with the comment above, go for option 1, but maybe between Questionnaire and Question

Comment: Questionnaire is in my application Survey. So Survey has_many Questions

Comment: And User has_many Surveys right? Then customize the questions for each Survey, remove relationships or create new Questions and appropriate relationships to add new questions. Only watch out to not let a user edit the 'standard' questions. So have them read-only or something. If you're afraid for maintainability, you could also still consider option 2 and have the join model polymorphic.

Comment: Yes, user has_many Surveys